# Iterating through point shapefiles, converting them to polyline shapefiles with unique names using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, for-loop

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    outfc = fc + "_l"
    arcpy.PointsToLine_management(fc, outfc)
```

it comes up with the error "Output Feature Class: Same as input". Looks like it didn't convert at all, and added an "l" in the case of one file
Bacon.shpl
instead of what I want (Bacon_l.shp)

I am really bad with for loops and iterators, and I'd do this in ArcMap if I didn't have to manually enter a billion files using the batch feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're just *appending* "_l" to the feature class path , rather than *inserting* it. And when the feature class is a shapefile, you end up with `"filepath.shp" + "_l"` which == `"filepath.shp_l"`

Try:

```
import os.path
import arcpy

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(fc)
    outfc = name + "_l" + ext
    arcpy.PointsToLine_management(fc, outfc)
```